# How to limit NestedSortables sublevels?

Tags: javascript, nested, mootools, submenu, nested-sortable

I use http://mootools.net/forge/p/nestedsortables to sort a list of li elements, now it can sort them to unlimited sublevels.
I need to limit it to only one sublevel.

https://jsfiddle.net/dq3xqvu9/

```
new NestedSortables('menu', {
  onStart: function(el) {  },
  onComplete: function(el) {  }
});
```

Good - I want to be able to move them to only one sublevel:

- List item

  - List item
  - List item
  - List item

NOT Good - by default NestedSortables allows you to move the items to unlimited sublevels like:

- List item

  - List item

    - List item

      - List item

Comment: There is a option to lock into _depth_ and a option to specify the _depthLevel_. Did you try that? Check here -> https://github.com/ryanmitchell/Nested-Sortables/blob/master/Source/nested-1.3.js#L315

Comment: I am not sure how I should use that. When I try 'lock: "depth"' I can't move the items anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these three restrictions to NestedSortables Class:

```
  abort += (this.getDepth(dest, (move == 'inside')) > 1);
  abort += ((move == 'inside') && (el.getFirst('ul') != null));
  abort += ((move != 'inside') && (el.getFirst('ul') != null) && (this.getDepth(dest, (move == 'inside')) > 0));
```

Complete code on [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq3xqvu9/1/).

This modification limits the number of sub-levels to 1.